# jquery UI missing scripts

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need urgent advice.
I was using following links form jQuery UI site:

http://ui.jquery.com/latest/ui/jquery.effects.core.js

http://ui.jquery.com/latest/ui/jquery.effects.slide.js

They stop working yesterday on my live site. I download and linked those 2 scripts to my local server, but  page  does not work Am I missing something else? Does anyone know other location for those files?

Any info is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you check firebug or javascript console log?

Comment: The new link for library is: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js

Comment: go to the page http://jqueryui.com/download/ and check/uncheck what you need, then download it. You will have the new version of your effect core and effect slide.

Comment: easy to check... open the script url in a browser...will see it is no longer there at that link. Docs have all download information

Comment: Thank you guys for the tip, I downloaded  code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js, as well as new scripts and it fixed it.